# Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 16 to the 15 allowed. How to refactor and reduce the complexity?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

How can I reduce the complexity of the bellow piece of code?
I am getting this error in SonarQube:

> Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 16 to the
> 15 allowed.

```
(function () {
  window.dm = window.dm || { AjaxData: [] };
  window.dm.AjaxEvent = function (et, d, ssid, ad) {
    dm.AjaxData.push({
      et, d, ssid, ad,
    });
    window.DotMetricsObj && DotMetricsObj.onAjaxDataUpdate();
  };
  const d = document;
  const h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  const s = d.createElement('script');
  let t = 'inews';
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;

  if (window.PageContext.categories) {
    for (let category of window.PageContext.categories) {
      if (Utils.categoryMap[category.slug]) {
        t = Utils.categoryMap[category.slug];
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (window.PageContext.post && window.PageContext.post.breadcrumbs) {
    for (let category of window.PageContext.post.breadcrumbs.reverse()) {
      if (Utils.categoryMap[category.slug]) {
        t = Utils.categoryMap[category.slug];
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}());

export default () => { };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can for example extract the complex `if` blocks to separate methods.

I mean these `if` blocks:

Extract to method 1 (eg `handleCategories`):

```js
  if (window.PageContext.categories) {
    for (let category of window.PageContext.categories) {
      if (Utils.categoryMap[category.slug]) {
        t = Utils.categoryMap[category.slug];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Extract to method 2 (eg `handleBreadcrumbs`):

```js
  if (window.PageContext.post && window.PageContext.post.breadcrumbs) {
    for (let category of window.PageContext.post.breadcrumbs.reverse()) {
      if (Utils.categoryMap[category.slug]) {
        t = Utils.categoryMap[category.slug];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

This will move around 3 complexity levels (`if` + `for` + `if`) from the original method to each of the extracted methods.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube should be telling you where each complexity point comes from. You'll see the most complexity accrued on those inner `if` statements. So anything you can do to reduce their complexity count is going to help a lot.

Inverted condition & early return is a favorite tactic of mine. Here's how it can help in this situation:

```
(function () {
  window.dm = window.dm || { AjaxData: [] };
  window.dm.AjaxEvent = function (et, d, ssid, ad) {
    dm.AjaxData.push({
      et, d, ssid, ad,
    });
    window.DotMetricsObj && DotMetricsObj.onAjaxDataUpdate();
  };
  const d = document;
  const h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  const s = d.createElement('script');
  let t = 'inews';
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;

  if (!window.PageContext.categories) {
    for (let category of window.PageContext.categories) {
      if (Utils.categoryMap[category.slug]) {
        t = Utils.categoryMap[category.slug];
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (!window.PageContext.post || !window.PageContext.post.breadcrumbs) {
    return;
  }
  for (let category of window.PageContext.post.breadcrumbs.reverse()) {
    if (Utils.categoryMap[category.slug]) {
      t = Utils.categoryMap[category.slug];
      break;
    }
  }

}());
```